# In Python Plotly, annotation is always on the top-left of a target point. How to annotate under a target point?

Tags: python, annotations, plotly

In Python, Plotly annotates always on the top-left of a target point (see the below line). However, I would like to annotate on the bottom-center of a point.

Please help with this. Thank you in advance for any comment.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'browser'

x = list(range(1, 10))
y = list(range(21, 30))

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y))

fig.add_annotation(x=x[4], y=y[4], arrowsize=2, text='Alway on the top-left')

pio.show(fig)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the parameters `ax` and `ay` to control the direction of the arrow (and the text will be positioned accordingly).

For example:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'browser'

x = list(range(1, 10))
y = list(range(21, 30))

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y))

fig.add_annotation(x=x[4], y=y[4], arrowsize=2, text='text underneath', ax=10, ay=30)

pio.show(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Before your reply, I spent hours and hours to figure out it, but I was failed. Your explanation and example is very much straightforward and easy to understand :)

Comment: @david78 you're welcome! when you have a chance, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as this will help people who have the same question as you in the future

Comment: I am sorry for forgetting about it. Now I have accepted it :)

Comment: No worries – much appreciated!